# Read in java (JDBC) a blob created with sqlite 3 in python

Tags: java, python, jdbc, sqlite, blob

I have a sql table that contains a blob generated 
using the following python commands:
sqlite3.Binary(numpy.float64(array))
or sqlite3.Binary(array).

I saved the database and now I would like to
load it with JDBC in java.
It seems that the getBlob method is deprecated, but
I can use the getBytes("myarray") to retrieve the array.
From that point it is unclear to me how to get my floats
or doubles back.
I found on the internet several more or less identical
"solutions". For the moment, I use something like the method 
I join below but it does'nt provide me with the expected
float values. What am I doing wrong or what do I forget ?

```
static float[] ConvertByteArrayToFloat(byte[] bytes)
{
    float[] floats = new float[bytes.length / 8];
    ByteBuffer buf2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    for (int i = 0; i < floats.length; i++){
        floats[i] = buf2.getFloat(i*8);
    }
    return floats;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried fiddling with the byte order settings on both the Python and Java sides?

Comment: thx. On the java side I played with the ByteBuffer.order() method. Is it what you mean ? And it did not help.

Comment: I had to convert the blob into a string. My array is now a very long string which increases by a factor 2 the size of the database. :) but at least it's working and this is what counts for the moment.

Comment: You should be able to do this without stringifying.  Try using data that is easier to investigate (like integers or chars)  to try to deduce endianness and padding.

Comment: What does sqlite3.Binary(numpy.float64(array)) return if you print it in console? Is it binary data? If yes then I am not sure whether Java will understand bin data generated in python. I may just convert it to a more portable format like XML or JSON and use getString to retrieve it.

Comment: One key thing: a numpy `float64` would be read out on the Java side with the `ByteBuffer.getDouble()` method; the names of the types on the two sides differ.